# Python Memory Error for large dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 270000 books rated by many people and I need to store deviations(its like any number) of one book with respect to all other remaining books.so its like I have 270000 outer keys in the dictionary and for each key in the outer keys I have 270000 keys again and deviation as  a value for each key...

so finally the dictionary structure is {1:{1:x1,2:x2,......270000:x270000},2:{},..........270000:{}} where 1,2,....270000 are book keys and x1,x2..x270000 are deviations and each sub-dictionary has same format as for sub-dictionary of key '1'

This dictionary while I am creating in the program I am getting python memory error but I need this to proceed further.

How to resolve this?

please help

Comment: WTF is `x1` in `{1:x1,...`?

Comment: consider a 2d numpy array?

Comment: Is every book rated by everyone? Am I reading it right?

Comment: x1 is the value of the deviation(it is a number) i.e the book 1's deviation w.r.t to itself.

Comment: Don't store all your deviations. Compute them dynamically and cache the most used ones. Hide this behind a dictionary interface if you need to by overloading the [].

Comment: @Gudavarthivamshi: Are you sure you need to store 73 billion elements? Can you not compute them and trade space for computational time?

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas DataFrame. You can read about it [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) and try optimize your code and data structure.

Perhaps you haven't use directory structure at all, but you can implement your task via numpy arrays, which is also a memory efficient data structure, but we should know more about your data to decide it.

Comment: Sample Data Format:'Daft Punk': {'Kacey Musgraves': 0.0, 'Imagine Dragons': 1.0, 'Fall Out Boy': 3.0, 'Lorde': 0.6666666666666666}, 'Kacey Musgraves': {'Daft Punk': 0.0, 'Imagine Dragons': 0.6666666666666666, 'Fall Out Boy': 2.6666666666666665, 'Lorde': 1.0}, 'Imagine Dragons': {'Daft Punk': -1.0, 'Kacey Musgraves': -0.6666666666666666, 'Fall Out Boy': 2.0, 'Lorde': -0.25}, 'Fall Out Boy': {'Daft Punk': -3.0, 'Kacey Musgraves': -2.6666666666666665, 'Imagine Dragons': -2.0, 'Lorde': -2.5}